# trying to reach a place in 2D array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to change values in a 2D array in java, but it's not working right for me , i want to reach array[3][3] and change all previous values to 9 in my way here is what i did:-

```
int gameLayout[][] = {
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    }, {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    }, {
        0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1
    }, {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    }, {
        0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
    }, {
        0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
    }, {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    }, {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1
    }, {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    }
};
System.out.println("this is the Layout of the game");
display(gameLayout);
for (a = y; a >= 0; a--) {
    for (int b = x; b >= 0; b--) {
        gameLayout[a][b] = 9;
    }
}
display(gameLayout);
public static void display(int array[][]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(array[row][column] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and here are the results I get:

9   9   9   9   0   0
9   9   9   9   0   0
9   9   9   9   0   0
9   9   9   9   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0

the 3 bottom rows haven't changed their values and are still 0.

The results I want are:

9   9   9   9   9   9
9   9   9   9   9   9
9   9   9   9   9   9
9   9   9   9   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0

How can I write that in java?

Comment: Post more code, what are x and y? Index you want to reach?

Comment: int gameLayout[][]={{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0}
    ,{0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1}
    ,{0,0,0,0,0,0}};
  System.out.println("this is the Layout of the game");
  display(gameLayout);

 for (a =y ; a >= 0 ; a--){
  for( int b =x; b >= 0; b--){
   gameLayout[a][b]= 9;
  }
 }
 display(gameLayout);
public static void display (int array[][]){
  for (int row =0 ; row < array.length; row++){
   for( int column =0; column< array[row].length; column ++){
    System.out.print(array[row][column]+ "\t" );
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me premise that your question is not clear to me. Why do you need both `x` and `y`? Isn't a single number `z` enough? I say that because it seems to me that you always "complete" the rows until you reach a certain point.
Also, why do you go bottom-up instead of top-down? Isn't that an unnecessary complication?

Suppose that you set `z = row_length*(x+1)`. In your case, `z = 6*4 = 24`.
So you can then write a clearer algorithm:

```
int z = row_length*(x+1);
//let's use c to keep track of the number of replacement until we reach z
int c = 1;
//let's give the outer loop a name so that we can terminate the whole procedure
//from the inner loop. I will call it "outerloop"
outerloop:
for(int a = 0; a < col_length; a++){ //this loops vertically
  for(int b = 0; b < row_length; b++) { //this loops horizontally
    gameLayout[b][a] = 9;
    c++;
    //and let's terminate loop when we are done!
    if (c == z)
      break outerloop; //done, party time!
  }
}
```

I hope that my assumptions on your problems are correct. Let me know if that is not the case.

Comment: I like your idea, but its still missing something, as to make it stop, still got to say when, and the condition up there "int z = row_length*(x+1);" not specific , but I like the idea of the loop, close enough , thanks , need some math to fix the equation of z.

Comment: It stops when you have reached z replacements. Well I am glad it helped :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are only filling up to x and y in each loop iteration.

It seems that you want to have a single dimensional array behavior when filling up the numbers, so consider you define it this way:

```
// x is the horizontal values to fill out, y is the vertical.
// Assuming gameLayout[x][y] gives the (x, y)'s square of the game.
// Also assuming the layout is a rectangle.
// We want to fill in y rows completely, then fill in x horizontal 
for (a = 0; a < y; a++){
    for (int b = 0; b < gameLayout.length; b++){
        gameLayout[b][a] = 9;
    }
}

// Now for the last row, we want to fill up to x, inclusive.
for (int b = 0; b <= x; b++){
    gameLayout[b][y] = 9;
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how your `gameLayout` is defined in terms of which index is x and which is y, but that should give you the right idea!

Comment: its defined as 
 0 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0 0

 0 0 0 0 0 0

all zero elements , and I wanna to reach some place and change all previous values to 9 .

Comment: What I'm saying is, what do the 0's represent? You said that `gameLayout` is a 2D array.

Comment: public static void display (int array[][]){
  for (int row =0 ; row < array.length; row++){
   for( int column =0; column< array[row].length; column ++){
    System.out.print(array[row][column]+ "\t" );
   }
   System.out.println();
   
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

/*here is the full code , im trying reach some place in the array [x][y]
and change all previous values to 9 as a mark that I went there, and trying to avoid the 1's is where I can't go*/

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.*;

  public class Main {
static int x =0;
static int y =0;
static int[][] gameLayout;
static int j =0;
static int k =0;
static int cost =0;
static int a =0;
static int b =0;
static int c =0;
static int d =0;

public static void main(String[] args){

    int gameLayout[][]={{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,1,1,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0}
            ,{0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,1}
            ,{0,0,0,0,0,0}};
    System.out.println("this is the Layout of the game");
    display(gameLayout);


    // setting initial state

System.out.println(" \n this is the intitial state at [0][0] \n");

System.out.println("enter where you wanna go in x & y coordinates");
// receiving input 
receiveInput();

checkGoal(gameLayout,x,y);



  // start moving and display current state and change its value to 9 

for (a =y ; a >= 0 ; a--){
    for( int b =x; b >= 0; b--){
        gameLayout[a][b]= 9;

    }
}
display(gameLayout);

}

// receive input function

public static int receiveInput(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    y = in.nextInt();
    x = in.nextInt();

    return y & x;
}

// the checkGoal function
public static int checkGoal(int anArray[][], int c , int v){
    c = x;
    v = y;

    if (c <0 || c >5 || v < 0 || v > 8){
        System.out.println("cant go there pick a valid place");
         return receiveInput();
    }

    if(anArray[c][v] == 1){
        System.out.println("cant go there pick a valid place");
         return receiveInput();
    }

    return x&y;
}


// the display function

public static void display (int array[][]){
    for (int row =0 ; row < array.length; row++){
        for( int column =0; column< array[row].length; column ++){
            System.out.print(array[row][column]+ "\t" );
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

}